Validation passes even though it is an invalid JWT
There are methods to create tokens and get user IDs while verifying the tokens,
Validation is valid even if you enter an invalid token value in certain situations.
public String generateToken(User user, Duration expiredAt) {
    Date now = new Date();
    return Jwts.builder()
            .issuer(jwtProperties.getIssuer())
            .subject(String.valueOf(user.getId()))
            .expiration(new Date(now.getTime() + expiredAt.toMillis()))
            .issuedAt(now)
            .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(jwtProperties.getSecretKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), Jwts.SIG.HS256)
            .compact();
}

public Long getUserId(String token) {
    try {
        return Long.valueOf(Jwts.parser()
                .verifyWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(jwtProperties.getSecretKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                .build()
                .parseSignedClaims(token)
                .getPayload()
                .getSubject());
    } catch (JwtException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

I thought there was a problem with the key, so I tried changing the algorithm, but it was the same.

In what situations? What token are you passing in?
